# reset is not a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code what i was trying:
Markup:

```
<textarea class="form-control textareaInput" rows="12" id="textareaInput"></textarea>
                    

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
        <div class="form-group">
             <button  class="form-control btn btn-primary reset" onclick="myFunction()">Reset</button>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**My function:**

```
function myFunction() {
  //alert("ok");
  document.getElementById("textareaInput").reset();
}
```

I am getting errors when I click on the `reset` button.
**Error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).reset is not a
> function

Where is the problem?
N.B: I was not using the `form` tag.

Comment: If you know you were not using a form, you know the error, right?

Comment: without using form i want to reset textarea.How can i do that? where is my problem?

Comment: You'll have to find an alternative, because `reset()`requires a `HTMLFormElement`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: The duplicate is wrong. It is regarding clearing input/textarea value, not reseting it. Now i'm quite sure in dupe or in this question or more obviously in both, there is a confusion between cleareing and resetting a input value. Clearing means set to empty value, where resetting means set it to any default value which could be any value, not necessary the empty string. `reset()` DOM node method of `form` element set values of any descendant ':input' to default one, not to empty string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use

```
document.getElementById("textareaInput").value = "";
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using a `form`, to reset a `textarea` or any other `input` element, just set its value to default one, using DOM node property `defaultValue`:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("textareaInput").value = document.getElementById("textareaInput").defaultValue;
}
```

In your case, because default value is empty string, you could just re-set it to empty string but this would be harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

The [HTMLFormElement.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) method restores a form element's default values. You Should USE `<form>` for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The .reset method available only for Form elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset), not for textarea or input DOM-elements. So, if you want to clear text in textarea, you can do it with two ways:

1. document.getElementById("textareaInput").value = '';
2. Wrap your textarea with form element, and use reset on it.

Comment: Just as a side note, the default value isn't always empty string

Answer (score 1):

put elements in form tag :

```
<body>
    <form>
<textarea class="form-control textareaInput" rows="12" id="textareaInput"></textarea>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
        <div class="form-group">
             <button  class="form-control btn btn-primary reset" onclick="myFunction()">Reset</button>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
        </form>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
  //alert("ok");
  document.getElementById("textareaInput").reset();
}
    </script>
</body>
```