# Error: .reset is not a function. How to reset form fields?

Tags: javascript, html

I have same problem as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37511093/4632019), but in my case I have form.

I do exactly how that is described by [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp):
[image]

Does any know what is the problem and how to reset form?

Answer (score 0):

I have found next [blog post](https://articles.runtings.co.uk/2011/06/solved-javascript-error-reset-is-not.html)

The author of the post blame in his source next line of code:

```
<input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
```

When I checked mine. I found this:

```
<button type="submit" class="button button_blue" name="reset">RESET PASSWORD</button>
```

Chaning the name from `reset` to `resetx` fixes the problem.